# Dimension of variety intersected with a hyperplane?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, krull-dimension

I have an affine variety $V$ defined over $\mathbb{C}$, defined as a zero set of some polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n]$. 
Let
$$
W = V \cap \{ x_n = 0 \}.
$$

I have two questions.

1. Does $W$  as an affine variety in $\mathbb{C}^n$ always have dimension $(\dim V) - 1$?
2. Since we are restricting to $x_n = 0$, I suppose we could view $W$ as an affine variety in $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$ also (I think... I might be confused about something here...). Is the dimension of $W$ as an affine variety in  $\mathbb{C}^n$ and  $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$ always the same?

Comment: What if $V$ is contained entirely in $\{x_n = 0\}$?

Comment: @Hoot I think it may or it may not... does the answer depend on this fact?

Comment: @JohnnyT. consider examples to see that it does depend! Clearly, if $V$ is contained in the hyperplane, the dimension of the intersection cannot be different from the dimension of $V$...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Ok, I get this part now. Thank you! How about the second part? Does the ambient space place a role in the dimension? or does it just affect the codimension?

Comment: The answer to 1. is Krull's Hauptidealsatz: is says that if $A$ is a Noetherian ring, and $f$ is a non-zero-divisor, then the dimension of $A/(f)$ is $n-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for 1 is no: just take $V$ to be the line $x_2=0$ inside $\mathbb{C}^2$ (the horizontal line). Then $\dim V=1$ and $\dim W=1$, since $W=V$. The point here is (as it appears in the comments) that $V$ is contained in the hyperplane in question.

For the question 2, I think that it is easier to look at the dimension of the variety as the Krull dimension of its coordinate ring. Say that $V$ is defined by some ideal $I\subset \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. In this case, $W$ can be viewed as the subvariety of $\mathbb{C}^n$ defined by $(I,x_n)\subset \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ or as the subvariety of $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$ defined by $$\overline{I}\subset \frac{\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]}{(x_n)}\simeq \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}]$$ where the "bar" represents residual classes.

The point is that the coordinate rings $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}]}{\overline{I}}$ and $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]}{(x_n,\,I)}$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb{C}$-algebras. It gives you that their Krull dimensions agree.